# Please clarify: Jenkins REST API with CSRF needs crumbs for user:PASSWORD, but not user:API_TOKEN?

Tags: jenkins, csrf, jenkins-api, csrf-token

I found that with [CSRF Protection enabled](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection), I can either issue a post request with crumbs header and using `username:PASSWORD` for the basic auth header:

```
String basic = "<username>:<PASSWORD>";
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://host.com/jenkins/quietDown").openConnection();
c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.addRequestProperty("Jenkins-Crumb", "<CRUMB>");
c.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(basic.getBytes()));
c.getInputStream().close();
```

or use `username:APITOKEN` for the basic auth header, in which case the crumbs header is not necessary:

```
String basic = "<username>:<APITOKEN>";
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://host.com/jenkins/quietDown").openConnection();
c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(basic.getBytes()));
c.getInputStream().close();
```

Question:

- Is this intended usage (username:APITOKEN without crumbs header)? The documentation and existing SO answers are vague.

Using Jenkins 2.164.3 and Java 8.