# Subversion post commit hook for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, svn, post-commit-hook, jenkins-api

I just spent a day wading through a decade's worth of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014252/jenkins-ci-how-to-trigger-builds-on-svn-commit), forum posts and the Jenkins Subversion Plugin [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) and [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/subversion).

The question I was trying to answer:

- What is the current minimal setup required to trigger jobs by Subversion commits?

Questions I couldn't answer:

- What are pros / cons of using `wget` vs `curl`?
- What is the effect of passing the `REV` parameter?

Working with Jenkins 2.164.3 and Subversion 1.9.7, each set up on it's own Ubuntu Server 18.04, and each behind it's own Apache HTTP Server with LetsEncrypt SSL certificates for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal svn post-commit hook that worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID="$(/usr/bin/svnlook uuid ${REPO})"
CHANGED="$(/usr/bin/svnlook changed -r ${REV} ${REPO})"    
SERVER_URL="https://<redacted>/jenkins"
USER="<redacted>"
API_TOKEN="<redacted>" # not the password

/usr/bin/curl -X POST -s -u "${USER}:${API_TOKEN}" -d "${CHANGED}" ${SERVER_URL}/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit
```

Notes:

- CSRF is enabled, but `USER:API_TOKEN` [seems to be enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138723/please-clarify-jenkins-rest-api-with-csrf-needs-crumbs-for-userpassword-but-n) (no need for crumbs).
- Not specifying any `Content-Type` headers seems to be just fine
- Not sending `?rev=${REV}` seems to be just fine (what's the difference?)
- Not necessary to configure special build trigger tokens (see screenshot)

Jenkins log output with (8,706) and without (-1) rev parameter:

```
May 15, 2019 8:04:28 PM INFO jenkins.scm.impl.subversion.SubversionSCMSource$ListenerImpl onNotify
Received post-commit hook from f9.... for revision [8,706 vs -1] on paths [project1/pom.xml, ...]
May 15, 2019 8:04:28 PM INFO jenkins.scm.impl.subversion.SubversionSCMSource$ListenerImpl onNotify
No subversion consumers for UUID f9....
May 15, 2019 8:04:28 PM INFO hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner run
SCM changes detected in project1. Triggering  #20
```

Job configuration:

[image]